# viewRender does not update calendar when eventsource is changed

Tags: fullcalendar

Whenever the user selects the calendar I need to go back to the server and refresh the data for the dates they have selected - so on next, prev, etc. buttons. I tested that the event source works if defined on the calendar - but defined this way does not get the events. How do I hook up the views, next, prev buttons with the ajax call?

```
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  var eventSource = {
    url: '/JVCalendar/GetJVCalendarEvents',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      start: "01/01/2015",
      end: "01/31/2015",
      calendarId: "1"
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }
  }
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventSource);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
}
```

Comment: sorry format is wrong:

Comment: fullcalendar already has buttons to change the views and go forward and backward? When you click them it will call your event source with the appropriate start and end parameters formatted like 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: It is calling the event source - but I only want to load events for month by month - so when they go into the next month - I need to go back to the server to get the events for that month.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgmjqL1q/) - the requestws event source URL is shown in the textarea above the calendar. When you click on the < or > buttons it shows the start and end dates are being updated on the endpoint URL; re-adding the event source each time is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as an answer since it's only mentioned in the comments. Credits go to @smcd. Finally found this after a lot of hassle.

fullCalendar already sends the `start` and `end` date by default. When looking in the network logs I can see the parameters being added automatically.

> api/v1/schedulings/fullcalendar?start=2016-02-28&end=2016-04-10&_=1458223901062